# Clone WebCam stream in mediastreamer2

Tags: opencv, stream, video-streaming, webcam, linphone

I'm using mediastreamer2 for a video stream from a Webcam, via a RTP connection to another System.

I want to have 2 (or more) outgoing video streams, the first one 
initialized works fine, but the second stream is complaining, that the WebCam is busy.

```
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
```

Do you have any hints, and/or ideas how to clone the webcam video stream or another way to implement 2 videostreams?

thanks in advance!
Mediastreamer2 is written in c , I'm using Ubuntu and Qt to code.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have a solution :

1. Loopback is a nice packet to make virtual Webcams.

   `sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms  //to install`
   `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=X  // X = number of virtual cams`
2. Copy Videosource from Real Webcam to Virtual ( [check this page](https://www.timdejong.nl/blog/use-webcam-two-applications-under-linux-simultaneously-using-v4l2loopback) )

   `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 352x288 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video1 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video2   // this copys from video0 to the VirtualCams video1`
3. Start Streams by selecting Virtual Cams

   `MSWebCam *cam = ms_web_cam_manager_get_cam(m,"V4L2: /dev/video1");`